# Angular routing module with query params

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

Helo all
I have some routes in routing module like this

```
  {
    path: 'contracts',
    component: ContractsComponent,
    canActivate: [ContractsGuardService],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ContractsSearchComponent,
        canActivate: [ContractsGuardService]
      },
      {
        path: 'contract/:details',
        component: ContractDetailsComponent,
        canActivate: [DetailsGuardService],
        resolve: { contractDetails: DetailsResolver }
      }
    ]
  }
```

The problem i have is that in contracts route i always have to have like this 
**?activeOnly=false** in url params, and when someone type url like this **/contracts** i have to redirect him to **/contracts?activeOnly=false**
is this something that i have to accomplish inside routing module?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can remove canActivate: [ContractsGuardService] from the child routes. It should be enough to have it on the parent.
2. I assume that the query parameter alters the ContractsSearchComponent's default filtering. I guess that you want to show both inactive and active when you have no query parameters. Then the query parameters makes sense. But if you as you wrote: allways need to add the parameter, then maybe you should let the ContractsSearchComponent show only the invalid entities. And then add queryparameter where you can set either 'both' or 'active'.

A third option would be to add more child routes:

```
{
    path: 'contracts',
    component: ContractsComponent,
    canActivate: [ContractsGuardService],
    children: [..]
},
{
   path:'contracts-inactive'
   redirectTo:'contracts?activeOnly=false'
},
{
   path:'contracts-active'
   redirectTo:'contracts?activeOnly=true'
}
```

Comment: Code does not work, I dont want to add another route, i need to just add activeOnly=false in /contract route. 1. is something that is not related to question, or maybe i am wrong?

Comment: But if you have a route like 'contracts', showing a list with all contracts, then its perfect to use a query parameter for filtering. What about my suggestion to change the default filtering in ContractsComponent? Set the default to show only inactive if you are disturbed by always need to set  ?activeOnly=false. You can do that inside ContractsComponent

Answer (score -1):

have you tried setting the `redirectTo` property to the route?

```
{
path: 'contracts',
component: ContractsComponent,
canActivate: [ContractsGuardService],
redirectTo: 'contracts?activeOnly=false',
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ContractsSearchComponent,
    canActivate: [ContractsGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'contract/:details',
    component: ContractDetailsComponent,
    canActivate: [DetailsGuardService],
    resolve: { contractDetails: DetailsResolver }
  }
]
```

}

Comment: main.ts:12 Error: Invalid configuration of route 'tabs/contracts': redirectTo and children cannot be used together